# showing menu without pressing menu button

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a menu which must be visible in my all the activities. There are around 5,6 activities in my application.

**So i created a menu but that menu appears after pressing menu button.I want to appear menu without pressing menu button.**

Please tell me the code that shows menu on start of any activity.

Answer (score 1):

I think it goes
To open:

`((Activity).mContext).openOptionsMenu();`

To close:

`((Activity).mContext).closeOptionsMenu();`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Activity.openOptionsMenu()` or `Activity.openContextMenu`
**EDIT:** If you are using API level 5 or above try overiding this method:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: I have done this but this show null pointer exception because at oncreate there is no menu created.

Comment: Please see the edited answer above and let me know if it works.

Comment: this shows error that method onAttachedWindow() is undefined for the type Activity so where should i put this method.

Comment: its onAttachedToWindow and not onAttachedWindow. Here is a reference of the function http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow()